# Convert List into a java script array using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using the jQuery auto complete feature, in which the value are to be stored in a java script array. I have created a function that gives a list with objects that contain user_id and user_name. How to convert it into an array.

```
public class DocModel
{
    [Required]
    public String dr_name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int dr_id { get; set; }
    public List<DocModel> GetUser()
    {
        SqlDataReader sdr = DataAccess.DataAccess.getAllDoctorNames();
        List<AECS1.Models.DocModel> DocList = new List<Models.DocModel>();
        Models.DocModel Doc;
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                Doc = new Models.DocModel();
                Doc.dr_id = (int)sdr["dr_id"];
                Doc.dr_name = (string)sdr["dr_name"];
                DocList.Add(Doc);
            }
        }
        return DocList;

    }
}
```

This is the view page :

```
$(function () {
    var docdata = [];


    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: docdata
    });
});
```

How to fill up this docdata array ?

Comment: you could return a JSON from DocList, actually you must since the data is going to be used in the autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to your model called ToJSON & use a JavaScript converter - either the one built in or even better, the JSON.net one & have this method return the json encoded string representing your array.

```
<script>
    var docdata = @Model.ToJson();
</script>
```

If you don't like having the method in your model, do the JSON conversion as you populate your model.

Answer (score 0):

Pass DocModels to view as model.

```
@model IEnumerable<DocModel>
```

And then

```
<script>
    var docdata = [
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        @: '@item.dr_name',
    }
    ];
</script>
```

Comment: This is problematic. You're only html escaping, not JavaScript escaping. Different rules apply.

Comment: Yes. Am getting the desired output with this. But how would i set values to the list elements ?